# Configuring Create.js (WYSIWYG editor)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

I am playing with an idea of using Create.js in my site (http://createjs.org/demo/hallo/). I am struggling with JS, and finding where I could enable editing on page load. (The default behavior is having to click the Edit button first.) Ideas?

Comment: that create.js seems pretty slick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to set  `state: 'browse'` to `state: 'edit'`  Doh!